# maximizing a ratio of sums

Tags: inequality, optimization

Consider 3 n-uplets of real positive values :

$a_i$ such that $\forall i , \frac{1}{X} \leq a_i \leq X$ where $X>1$

$b_i$ such that $\forall i , \frac{1}{Y} \leq b_i \leq Y$ where $Y>1$

and $p_i$ such that $\sum{p_i}=1$ and $\forall i , p_i>=0$

I want to find an upper bound of the ratio : $R=\frac{\sum{p_i.a_i.b_i}}{\sum{p_i.a_i}\sum{p_i.b_i}}$

My intuition is that R reach its maximal when $a_i$ and $b_i$ take only extreme values (X,$\frac{1}{X}$, Y and $\frac{1}{Y}$) and that the indices i for which $a_i=X$ are also those for which $b_i=Y$.
That is a and b take their maximum values and their minimum values together.

With those additional restrictions, I achieved to solve the problem in the following way :

First, I consider $t=\sum\limits_{i|a_i=X}{p_i}$, then I express R as a function of t and find the maximum : $R(t)<=(\frac {1+XY}{X+Y})^2$

But, I would like to find a proof that R can not be higher outside of the restriction.

Comment: I'd say that : if the $p_i$ were constant, you could apply the [wiki/Hölder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Notable_special_cases). then suppose that the $p_i$ are all rational, and show that it reduces to the first case, finally extend this to the general case.

Comment: You seek an inequality of form:
$$R\left(\sum_i p_i a_i\right)\left(\sum_i p_i b_i \right)\geqslant \sum_i p_i a_i b_i$$
which also permits equality. As $LHS - RHS$ is a linear function in any of $a_i$ or $b_i$, so extreme values will only be at the boundary of the interval as you intuit.  Rearrangement on the RHS also shows at extremum $a_i, b_i$ are similarly arranged. Haven't checked the rest of your work though...